# CMD 'START' command assigns the wrong title

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-console

When I try assigning a title to a console window using the command `Start`, the word "Select" sometimes gets concatenated to the beginning of the title.
For instance if I write:

```
start  /affinity 0x1 "My_title" .\My_exe.exe input_file.cas
```

The title of the console window becomes "SelectMy_title" instead of "My_title".
This problem occurs occasionally. Would it be because of having a process with the same name running in the background?

Comment: `start /?` from a command line explains the parameters (and the order in which they appear). I'd start there.

Comment: `cmd` (actually, the console host process) changes the window title to start with `Select` exactly when you start selecting stuff with the mouse. You can end that with `Esc`. Either that's going on, or it's surely not a coincidence.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, the console host does that (e.g. conhost.exe). It has nothing to do with the CMD shell. But otherwise that's a good observation.